# What Unicode character represents "Add User/Account"

Tags: html, unicode

As the Title says, I want to have a button in HTML which should add users to my database. Alright, I have that. Now I want it to display a symbol representing this feature. I only want to use images as a last resort. So do you have any suggestions for my needs? Haven't found anything by simply asking Google.

To be specific, the character should have a silhouette of an upper body and a plus sign.

Comment: Try [Fontawsome](https://fontawesome.com). Its wiedly used for this purpose.

Comment: This question may be better suited for [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I've seen this type of question plenty of times here. Thought wasn't that much of a deal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of Unicode symbols which look like "user".

`U+1F464` Bust in Silhouette

`U+1F465` Busts in Silhouette

You will need to test with users to see which they associate more with "Add User".  You might need to use a couple of characters.  For example

## ➕

Or, if your users are technologists, doctors, students etc you could use their emoji.

## ‍ ‍⚕️ ‍

Answer (score 0):

As of Unicode 12.1, there is no such symbol expressing this meaning.

Do use an image, e.g. https://material.io/resources/icons/static/icons/baseline-person_add-24px.svg